# A game of add at most 10

Tags: algorithms

This is the problem:

There are two players A and B. Player A starts and chooses a number in the range 1 to 10. Players take turn and in each step add a number in the range 1 to 10. The player who reaches 100 first wins.

In the program, player A is the user and player B is the computer. Besides that the computer must force a win whenever possible. For instance, if the player A reaches 88 at some point, the computer must choose 89, as this is the only way to force a win.

The problem i face is how do I do the forcing on the part of the computer. Need some guidance on that.

Comment: I recommend that you study [Winning Ways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winning_Ways_for_your_Mathematical_Plays) by Berlekamp, Conway and Guy. It is full of more interesting games than this one, and describes theory and algorithms for finding the winning strategy. True, once you absorb the full theory of a game like this, it instantly becomes kinda boring :-(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First player starts with $1$ and then at each turn after picks $11-n$ where $n$ was the other player's choice. That means the numbers are $11k+1$ after first player's turn, and therefore you get to $89$ at turn $9$.

If first player even chooses any other value, then second player should choose so the sum is $11k+1$ for some $k$ and can force a win.

Comment: both players are free to type in any value right?

Comment: What do you mean? I was giving an algorithm to ensure a win. If at any time, you can add to get a number equal to $11k+1$, then you should do so. If you can't choose such a number, then you can't force a win. If you can, you can force a win.

Comment: can give an example?

Comment: If it is my turn and the current total is 37, I pick $8$ to give a total of $45=11\cdot 4 + 1$. Then I can force win. If the current total is $34$, however, I cannot force a win, my opponent can.

Comment: thanks for the example, clearer now.in the case of 34, the computer still has to input a value between 1 to 10, so it will input 1. am i right?

Comment: The computer can input any value if it is $34$, it doesn't have any strategy for forcing a win, and whatever it chooses, the user can force a win.

Comment: thanks a lot. Can explain how you get 11k+1?

Comment: It was based on the idea of getting to $89$. If I can pick $89$ then I can pick $100$. If I can pick $78,$ I can pick $89$ next and win. If I can pick $67$ then next turn I can pick $78$, etc. So, once I've picked $11k+1$, I can pick $11k+12=11(k+1)+1$ next turn, eventually leading to $11\cdot 9 +1$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume we will add in range $1$ to $a$ ($1 \leq a$) and we want to reach $0 \leq b$. Then, you should stay on the numbers which gives ($b$ mod $a+1$) in mod $a+1$. For example, if $a = 10$ and $b = 100$, you should say $1,12,23,34,45,56,67,78,89$. So, if you start, say $1$ and whatever computer says, say $12$ (and you can do that because computer can't say $12$ but whatever it says you can say it) and go like that, win!

For example, when you said $1$, it can say only $2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11$ and you can say $12$ in any situation, and this goes like that.

Also you might want to think about that for fun: Let's assume we can add the numbers in a set $S$, and we want to reach $x$. Is there an algorithm which gives exact solution (as like I gave in first paragraph for a special $S$) for any $S$?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a recursive function $f:\{0,...,100\}\to \{0,1\}$ where $f(n)=1$ if and only if the current player can win, equivalent can force his opponent to lose, when he have number $n$. $f(n)=0$ otherwise. Note that $f(100)=0$. Now for $n<100$

$$f(n)=1-min\{f(n+1),f(n+2),...,f(min(n+10,100))\},$$

so you win, $f(n)=1$, if and only if in some election from $1$ to $10$ your opponent lose. Then the best choice will be some number $i$ from $1$ to $10$ such that $f(n+i)=0$, so you will win because $f(n)=1-0=1$. In your example, when $A$ reaches $88$, the player $B$ will choice $i=1$ because $f(n+i)=f(88+1)=f(89)=0$, because player $A$ will not have choice for win with $n=89$.